# go lang net/http request pattern

Tags: rest, go

I'm writing a simple rest api server and I cannot get route dynamic url using net/http

- http://localhost:8080/book/**name**

where **name** can be any string.

this was my attempt:

```
func viewIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, 'html')
}

http.HandleFunc("/book/{name}", view)
```

this does not work, there is some cryptic note in the documentation of **HandleFunc**:

> The documentation for ServeMux explains how patterns are matched.

Comment: To handle something like this in go, I recommend using a external library like [gorilla mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux)

Comment: Register the pattern `"/book/"`, it matches the rooted subtree `/book/*`.

Comment: You are using view not viewIndex ? Can you clear what do you mean by this does not work

Comment: The documentation for ServeMux is on the page where you found the cryptic note.  https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux

Comment: @icza this is it! /book/ and in view func handling http.Request.Url, Thank you this solved my problem!

Comment: @poWar my initial goal was to stay with net/http I will definitely jump to an external library for next projects.

Comment: @MuffinTop honestly this did not help :/

Comment: @dawid I was trying to help by explaining what the "cryptic" comment referred to.  What aspect of the documentation are you having trouble with?

Answer (score -1):

This is a working solution.
The only interesting part it that patterns ending with **/** will be treated as prefix matcher for all urls.

So pattern **/book/** will match:

- /book/
- /book/a
- /book/bb
- /book/a/b

sample simplified code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"
        "net/http"
)

func book(name string) {
  fmt.Printf("requesting book '%s'\n",name);
}

func view(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := r.URL.String()
    if strings.HasPrefix(url, "/book/"){
      name := url[6:]
      book(name)
      fmt.Fprint(w, name)
    }
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/book/", view)
  http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}
```